# use java8 stream api to accumulation find index for limit 10

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am learning java8 stream api. igot face this problem.
Here have 9 number "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9".
I want find n for 1+2+3+....+n>=10 .
How can I use java8 stream api to find n?

i tried use for loop to find n, code like this:

```
int sum,n=0;
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    sum+=arr[i]
    if(sum>=10){
        n=i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: At present, java stream api is not suitable to solve this problem

Answer (score 3):

```
int n = IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
        .filter(i -> Arrays.stream(arr).limit(i + 1).sum() >= 10)
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(-1);
System.out.println(n); // return 3 (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10)
```

Comment: This looks like it would produce the correct answer (+1), but I wonder if it can be done more efficiently (i.e. avoid calculating the partial sums again and again in each execution of `filter()`).

Comment: I dont think you will get a more efficient code than your existing code with Streams. Just all the method calling already will make it slower than your code.

Comment: "it can be done more efficiently" - it's possible, but using side-effect, like variable outside Stream (that is bad design for Stream). Stream is more effective for working with separate elements, when order doesn't metter .

Comment: thanks,my leader let me  use "java stream api" to instead of "for statement" ,may be a mistake

Comment: @ViacheslavVedenin even then, it would be nice only for a sequential stream - for parallel, not even an `AtomicInteger` would help

Comment: Of course, but for parallel and a consequential  stream, it's impossible task in any case.

Comment: @Eugene you could do something like `Stream.iterate(new int[2], a -> new int[]{ a[0]+1, a[1]+arr[a[0]]}) .dropWhile(a -> a[1]<threshold) .mapToInt(a -> a[0]) .findFirst()`, but compared to the loop which can be written as a one-liner...

Comment: @Holger very nice! haven't thought of that

Answer (score 1):

Your code is contradicting your problem description. You say that you want *n* such that `1+2+3+....+n>=10`, but you are assigning `i`, the *index* of *n* in the array to `n`. Theses two correlate only if you have these ascending numbers in the array, but if you assume that fixed content, you wouldn't need  the array at all.

Further, you are not incrementing `sum` at all; it's zero all the time.

If you assume a sequence of ascending integers only, you can get *n* without iterating:

```
int threshold = 10;

long n = Math.round(Math.sqrt(threshold*2));//that's it
System.out.println("solution: n = "+n);

// the rest is only verification and reporting
long actualSum = LongStream.rangeClosed(1, n).sum();
assert actualSum >= threshold;
assert actualSum - n < threshold;

System.out.println(LongStream.rangeClosed(1, n)
    .mapToObj(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(" + ")));
System.out.println("\t = "+actualSum+" >= "+threshold);
```

If you want to get the solution for an arbitrary sequence stored in an array, a loop is the simplest and most efficient sequential solution:

```
int i, sum;
for(i = 0, sum = 0; i < arr.length && sum < threshold; i++) sum += arr[i];

if(sum >= threshold) {
    System.out.println("solution: index = "+(i-1)+", n = "+arr[i-1]);
    System.out.println(Arrays.stream(arr, 0, i)
            .mapToObj(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(" + ")));
    System.out.println("\t = "+sum+" >= "+threshold);
} else {
    System.out.println("No solution with this array");
}
```

If you have a large array and want to utilize parallel processing, you may use

```
Arrays.parallelPrefix(arr, Integer::sum);
int i = Arrays.binarySearch(arr, threshold);
if(i < 0) i = -i-1;

if(i < arr.length){
    System.out.println("solution: index = "+i+", n = "+(arr[i]-(i==0? 0: arr[i-1])));
    System.out.println(arr[0]+" + "+IntStream.rangeClosed(1, i)
        .mapToObj(ix -> String.valueOf(arr[ix]-arr[ix-1]))
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" + ")));
    System.out.println("\t = "+arr[i]+" >= "+threshold);
} else {
    System.out.println("No solution with this array");
}
```

But this modifies the array. This modification is reversible, as the example demonstrates, we can print the original sequence, but such a modification may not always be feasible. If we have to make a copy or transform the array back to its original state, we may already lose any advantage of parallel processing, so the loop stays the best option in these cases. You need a sufficiently large array anyway, to have a chance of getting a performance benefit from parallel processing.

Comment: to be honest I thought about this `long n = Math.round(Math.sqrt(threshold * 2));` but it assume a contiguous array, don't know if OP really means that

Comment: @Eugene that's why I made that distinction.

Comment: thanks,I have modified my code.I think java stream api to do it too complicated,Poor readability and performance